# I'm trying to look at all of the files in a directory using bash, and then comparing the sizes

Tags: bash

I'm working on finding the three smallest files in a directory and then displaying useful information with the stat command, but I can't get the script to read the correct directory.

The directory is getting passed into the script, and whenever I pass in the directory it is telling me it doesn't exist.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will find the files in a directory with the smallest size and print out the properties for those files.
filepath='$1'
smallestFileSize=10000000000000000000000000
secondSmallestSize=10000000000000000000000000
thirdSmallestSize=10000000000000000000000000
smallestFile=''
secondSmallestFile=''
thirdSmallestFile=''
for file in '$filepath'
do
  if [ $(stat -c %s file) -lt '$smallestFileSize' ]
  then
     '$smallestFileSize'=$(stat -c %s file)
     '$smallestFile'=file
  fi
  if [ $(stat -c %s file) -lt '$secondSmallestSize' && $(stat -c %s file) -gt '$smallestFileSize' ]
  then
     '$seondSmallestSize'=$(stat -c %s file)
     '$secondSmallestFile'=file
  fi
  if [ $(stat -c %s file) -lt '$thirdSmallestSize' && $(stat -c %s file) -gt '$secondSmallestSize' ]
  then
     '$thirdSmallestSize'=$(stat -c %s file)
     '$thirdSmallestFile'=file
  fi
done < '$filepath'

stat -c '%i %b %A %h %U %G %s $y' '$smallestFile'
stat -c '%i %b %A %h %U %G %s $y' '$secondSmallestFile'
stat -c '%i %b %A %h %U %G %s $y' '$thirdSmallestFile'
```

Comment: Single quotes don't do what you think.  Please paste your code into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the errors that it reports.  If you are still having problems after that or you don't understand what it is telling you, then ask a question.

Comment: `zsh -c 'stat *(oL[1,3])'`

Comment: Note that `stat` is not part of bash, it's a completely separate binary whose behaviour and usage depends on your operating system. I run bash in FreeBSD, where the command to get the size of a file might be `stat -f '%z' "$filename"`. Definitely a good idea to specify your platform if your code depends on platform-specific tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your script had a plenty of errors, mostly of them were syntax and typo errors. I fixed them (but this script has several limitations e.g. the file names cannot have spaces):

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script will find the files in a directory with the smallest size and print out the properties for those files.
filepath="$1"
smallestFileSize=""
secondSmallestSize=""
thirdSmallestSize=""
smallestFile=""
secondSmallestFile=""
thirdSmallestFile=""
for file in "$filepath"/*
do
  size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
  if [ -z "$smallestFileSize" ]
  then
    smallestFileSize=$size; smallestFile="$file"
    secondSmallestSize=$size; secondSmallestFile="$file"
    thirdSmallestSize=$size; thirdSmallestFile="$file"
  fi

  if [ "$size" -lt "$smallestFileSize" ]
  then
     smallestFileSize=$size
     smallestFile="$file"
  fi
  if [ "$size" -lt "$secondSmallestSize" -a "$size" -gt "$smallestFileSize" ]
  then
     secondSmallestSize="$size"
     secondSmallestFile="$file"
  fi
  if [ "$size" -lt "$thirdSmallestSize" -a "$size" -gt "$secondSmallestSize" ]
  then
     thirdSmallestSize="$size"
     thirdSmallestFile="$file"
  fi
done

stat -c "%i %b %A %h %U %G %s %N" "$smallestFile"
stat -c "%i %b %A %h %U %G %s %N" "$secondSmallestFile"
stat -c "%i %b %A %h %U %G %s %N" "$thirdSmallestFile"
```

But there's a simpler way to achieve the same result:

```
$ ls -1S | tail -3 | tac | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%i %b %A %h %U %G %s %N"
```

**Explanation**

- `ls -1S`: list sorting by size (largest first).
- `tail -3`: print only last 3 lines
- `tac`: `cat` inverted: just prints the input (last line first).
- `xargs -d '\n'`: execute the next arguments appending an argument with each read line.

**Example**

```
$ ls -l
total 1264
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 101637 Mar 22 21:59 01.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 107713 Mai 30 15:45 02.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 244813 Mai 30 16:18 03.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 147281 Set  4 23:40 04.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier  69379 Set  4 23:52 05.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 535752 Ago 28  2014 06.dat
-rw------- 1 wpomier wpomier  75021 Set  4 23:59 07.dat

$ ls -1S | tail -3 | tac | xargs -d '\n' stat -c "%i %b %A %h %U %G %s %N"
2491705 144 -rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 69379 '05.dat'
20327657 152 -rw------- 1 wpomier wpomier 75021 '07.dat'
20316583 200 -rw-rw-r-- 1 wpomier wpomier 101637 '01.dat'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bash loop that:

1. Finds all files in /var/log ( for ex. ), ...
2. gets each file size, ...
3. sort output of file list with size by number value, ...
4. head prints first 3 lines, ...
5. awk prints only second column ( path to file ) .

`` for file in `find /var/log -type f -exec du -s '{}' \; | sort -n | head -n 3 | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do stat -c '%i %b %A %h %U %G %s $y' "${file}"; done ``